# How to get an txt file output with visible moviclips on stage to SQL database with AS3?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3

I have no idea about SQL but I have this college prj. to be submitted.

Basicallyits a color change game where all movieclips are visible to false. When select a shirt button and click red button that color MC will be visible to true.

Now I want the end product that is the user while clicking the save button, I want all the movieclips that r visible on stage to be generated as a list to be sent to SQL database and also to server.

How could I go about it?

Any suggestions and ideas r welcome and much appreciated..

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is create a local database, and store what you need to store in it, 
Here is an [example](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/25) about how to create / use SQLite

Some documentation that will help you : [SQLConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html), [SQLStatement](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLStatement.html)

PS : This is a simple thing that you should have found it if you googled for it ...

Comment: Thank You. But how could I just get these movieclips instances to the database file?? I am so confused. And I have an .fla file.

Comment: Store the swf it self, I don't think it's possible, I think you should save the file in a directory, store the path and it's settings on the database ...

Comment: I have an swf from which I have to add the data to database. Also its an db file. Everything will be done from server itself I think. The only thing I want to know is how to call functions to give data to that database?  Please help.

Comment: I guess this answer is what you need, [Upload file to server in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245682/upload-file-to-server-in-as3), And if it's just to send the data of your form, use this [Sending and recieving data from AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876588/sending-and-receiving-data-from-flash-as3-to-php)

Comment: Thank You. I will go through wit this

Comment: I have another doubt. How to change the flash file to get those movieclips to POST to server?? Any idea.. Please help.